# cannot read property 'local' of undefined error installing Visual Studio extensions

Tags: xubuntu, extension, visual-studio-code

So I installed Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu 18.04 and all seems well , except when I install an extension, any, It fails with 
cannot read property 'local' of undefined

it offers me the blue button to download manually and i do and find the local file and it also fails with same error. I believe its something to do with local permissions. but I give all the directories the

sudo chmod -R +rwx ~/anaconda3

same with directories with my application files

so no idea what do do next. a search for this error message comes back empty. believe it or not. Im starting to see that VSC is not used a lot on linux, so little support issues found. Mostly windows info.

Im only using VSC cause my tutorial is using it. :-/

any help appreciated.

Comment: What's your VSC version? It could be a bug, but I had to look it up first

Comment: @Emmet it says 1.32 3. Im on. Ubuntu 18.04 64 bit 4.15.0-46 . all kinds of errors with even running file in terminal. I installed with and without sudo.